# Using C++ protobuf formatted structure in leveldb. set/get operations

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, leveldb

I'd like to make a POC of using leveldb in order to store key-value table of different data types in protobuf format.

So far I was able to open the database file, and I also saw the get function with the following signature :

`virtual Status Get(const ReadOptions& options, const Slice& key, std::string* value)=0`

I understand that the value is actually refers to a binary string like vector and not regular alphanumeric string, so I guess it can fit for multi type primitives like string, uint, enum) but how can it support struct/class that represent protobuf layout in c++ ?

So this is my proto file that I'd like to store in the leveldb:

```
message agentStatus {
    string ip = 1;
    uint32 port = 2;
    string url = 3;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_seen = 4;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_keepalive = 5;
    bool status = 6;
}
```

and this is my current POC code. How can I use the `get` method to access any of the variables from the table above ?

```
#include <leveldb/db.h>


void main () { 

  std::string db_file_path = "/tmp/data.db";
  leveldb::DB* db;
  leveldb::Status status;

  leveldb::Options options;
  options.create_if_missing = false;
  status_ = leveldb::DB::Open(options, db_file_path, &db);
  if (!status_.ok()) {
    throw std::logic_error("unable to open db");
  }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to serialize the protobuf message into a binary string, i.e. `SerilaizeToString`, and use the `Put` method to write the binary string to LevelDB with a key.
2. Then you can use the `Get` method to retrieve the binary value with the given key, and parse the binary string to a protobuf message, i.e. `ParseFromString`.
3. Finally, you can get fields of the message.

Comment: Thanks for you response ... When i create a protobuf message, the fields should have a specific type... I wonder if protobuf support genetic field type that is suitable for arbitrary data type ?

Comment: You can take a look at [google.protobuf.Struct](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto)